# junitのテストメソッドが通らない。エラーを解決したい。

Tags: junit

**ソースコード**

```
@InjectMocks
public class test1{

    @Test
    public void 02(){
        assertEquals("12345", target.encode(null));
    }

}
```

**エラーメッセージ**

```
java.lang.AssertionError:expected<123>but was<null>
```

と出ました。

`assertEquals` のメソッドを使うと `assertEquals("12345", target.encode(12345));`
引数とリターンの値の一致をみるのでエラーとなってしまいます。

#### 実現したいこと

引数を `"12345"` がきたとして、返却を `null` としてテストメソッドを実行したい。
→ `assertEquals("12345", target.encode(null));`

引数 `"12345"` に対して、`null` を返すことを成功としたい場合どうしたらいいのかわかりません。
教えて頂きたいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ご質問の

> 引数 "12345" に対して、null を返すことを成功としたい場合どうしたらいいのかわかりません。

については、assetNull()を使ってください、ということになりますが、提示されているコードを見ると、何か誤解されている部分があるのではないかと思いまして、蛇足ながら説明します。

```
 assertEquals("12345", target.encode(null));
```

は`target.encode(null)`の戻り値が`"12345"`であることを期待している記述です。
`target.encode()`の実装が記載されていないため推測ですが、`target.encode("12345")`として戻り値をチェックするべきではないでしょうか。